# ActiveMQ Dead Letter Box.queue - Messages are going straight there?

Tags: jmeter, activemq-classic

when running my JMeter Test Plans using the JMS Publisher/Subscriber elements it appears to run successfully sending track data to a web page. I can see the response data OK in JMeter. However, no tracks appear. So when looking in the JMS Browser it appears the messages are going straight to the ActiveMQ DLB.queue.

Any clues where the issue may be ?

Answer (score 1):

The fact you're able to send the messages doesn't necessarily mean they are received by the recipient.

Unfortunately we're not telepathic enough in order to state what's wrong without knowing at least your JMeter and ActiveMQ broker configurations.

So I can only recommend double checking the topic names in order to get the confidence that you're sending messages to the correct destination.

You might also want to [increase JMeter's logging verbosity for the JMS protocol](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html) - this way you will be able to see way more information regarding what's going in in [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging). Add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.jms" level="debug" />
```

You might also want to check [Building a JMS Topic Test Plan](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-jms-topic-test-plan.html) article

Comment: Thanks, will try what you have suggested.